# Fastest way to test two strings for exact match in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string-matching

I want to compare two strings in **JavaScript** to test if they are *exactly* the same.
Which would be the best (fastest) way to do this?

Right now, I'm considering either

```
if(string1.localeCompare(string2) == 0) {}
```

or simply

```
if(string1 == string2)
```

Is there a better way do to this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I would probably use [strict equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons) if you want to check they are *exactly* the same, ie they're the same *type* too, just in case.

```
if (string1 === string2)
```

Comment: Is that the fastest solution, as requested? If so, can you add supporting evidence?

Comment: @LeeGoddard you're asking about an answer I wrote a decade ago. Run the tests yourself if you want.

Answer (score 6):

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ACtq9/2/)* and figure out yourself which one is faster.

*In case the link dies in the future: `==` > `===` > `String.localeCompare` (tested on Chrome).

Comment: But, as stated in an answer and comment, `==` does not even meet the requirement of checking for an exact match, at least not in the uninformed case.

Comment: @IngoBürk Yeah I know. But still for cases when you do not need strict comparison == is faster. That's only an information, I showed the speeds and choosing the method is only up to you :)

Comment: Just what I needed. @IngoBürk, while you're *strictly* correct, I think the meaning of exact is highly contextual.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure there is any room to optimize `if(string1 == string2)`.  That is the best approach.

Comment: Unless you already know that they are strings, using `===` is essential.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (typeof string1=="string" && typeof string2=="string" && string1 === string2)
```

no escape method :)

Comment: I like the thought, but you can omit the second `typeof`.